# Any way te read an excel file from a Google Sheet?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-apps

in my organization we work with Google Apps but we have one file that we need to maintain in Excel due to its complexity. All my other spreadsheets are Google Sheets and a lot of them need to get data from that excel file. So my question is: is there a way either trough google scripts or excel publishing to get data from an excel file in Google Drive to a Google Sheet?

I know all about the other direction, Google to Excel, but Excel to Google is proven more complicated. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im giving you an algorithmic-level answer without code because you also have none.

with apps script you can import the xls to drive as a new spreadsheet at regular intervals. then, copy its contents to a fixed spreadsheet (replacing previous content).

other spreadsheets can read from that fixed sprradaheet with scripts/importrange etc.